# what is the best way to structure this query

Tags: linq, collections

I have a IEnumerable collection of objects.  The objects have a field **LastedUpdated** which is a **DateTime** field.

I want to filter the collection, given a timestamp that I have, to return the record in the collection with that timestamp and the "next record" in time (based on this field) because I then want to have some code do a "diff" between the two different records to show what has changed.

I am trying to figure out the best way to take a collection and do this filtering possibly using LINQ

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
var results = (from o in objects
  where o.lastupdated >= tstamp
  orderby o.lastupdated
  select o).Take(2);
```

Comment: That returns a result even if nothing actually matches the timestamp, which may or may not be OK.

Comment: @mquander -  just a fyi, in my case there is always going to be a match

Comment: this above doesn't compile (has to be orderby)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most efficient, but unless you think performance is an issue, I'd consider it clearest.

```
var objsByDate = objects.OrderBy(x => x.LastedUpdated).ToArray();
int matchIdx = Array.FindIndex(objsByDate, x => x.LastedUpdated == timestamp);

if (matchIdx >= 0)
{
    var match = recentObjects[matchIdx];
    var next = recentObjects[matchIdx + 1]; // assuming it exists
}
```

Comment: i would like it to be as fast as possible as I am hovering over some text on a webpage and i am doing an ajax call to populate a tooltip.

Comment: @ooo: Unless there are at least thousands of objects, this will be imperceptibly fast.  If there are indeed thousands or more objects, I suggest that you consider using a sorted data structure, and also suggest that you use binary search to find the right ones instead of a linear search.  I'm not sure what you mean by indexing not working -- this code runs verbatim for me.